# How do we handle edits that change the code in an answer?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

<sub>Sorry if this is a duplicate, I haven't seen a post that covers this topic before.</sub>

I have seen many edits recently that edit the original answers code in an attempt to help golf it. I saw somewhere (sorry, don't remember where) that you shouldn't edit the code in other peoples posts. How are we supposed to handle edits that do this?

Examples:

- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27156
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27131
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27016
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26862

Comment: Looks right, flag as a dupe.